# IISnode application info

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, isomorphic-javascript, iisnode

I have a Project which I want to access from multiple IIS applications, each hosted at a different port.
Lets say, we have the following folder structure:

**MyProject**

- **Application 1** (has its server.js file and web.config)

and I have these applications in my IIS:

---

**Website 1**: hosted at http://localhost:8080 has an application

**App** - points to Application1 above - **http://localhost:8080/App**

---

**Website 2**: hosted at http://localhost:8082 has an application -

**SomeOtherApp** - points to Application1 above - **http://localhost:8082/SomeOtherApp**

---

How do I get the IIS Application host info in the server.js file, just like I can get the port info by using process.env.PORT?

I need the ***application name info*** ( /App or /SomeOtherApp ) and the ***host info*** (localhost:8080 or localhost:8082) in the **server.js** file before i start the app.

I know that we can get app this info from req.headers once the app starts, but i need it before the app starts. And since the web.config is also common to both applications I cannot set these there.

Can we get this information from IISnode?? If not, is there some other platform which can give me this information in the server.js file?

Thanks.